# How to get a property name of a given type strongly typed revisited?

Tags: system.reflection

How can I simplify the code below to avoid to pass the object for type inference on the generic method?

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace lambda
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var area = new Area { Name = "New Area" };
            var propertyName = area.GetPropertyName(area, a => a.Name); // propertyName is COMPILE time checked

            Console.WriteLine(propertyName);

        }
    }

    public class Area
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Extension
    {
        public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this Area entity, T e, Expression<Func<T, object>> path) // T e for type inference
        {
            var member = path.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (member == null) throw new ArgumentException();
            return member.Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I mean instead of calling the extension method with   area.GetPropertyName(area, a => a.Name)
 just do a call like this area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Name), avoid to pass there area object just for type inference

I guess that I can’t do unless I refactor the signature of the method to GetPropertyName(this IEntity entity,  Expression> path)
But in that case will be less obvius want I want at code writing time since I will need to specify the type on every call 
I mean area.GetPropertyName( a => a.Name) seems to bel for me less clear writing code than writing area.GetPropertyName(area, a => a.Name)

Answer (score 0):

The example code below works fine with asked requirements, no need to pass the object itself for type inference when calling the extension method
I used a base class and an interface that for my case works fine for all my domain class.
See code below

```
namespace UnitTestProject
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public interface IEntity<T>
    {
    }

    public abstract class Entity<T> : IEntity<T> where T : class
    {
    }

    public class Area : Entity<Area>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public bool Closed { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public static class EntityExtension
    {
        public static string GetPropertyName<T>(this IEntity<T> entity, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr) // T e for type inference
        {
            var unary = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
            var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            return member != null ? member.Member.Name : (unary != null ? ((MemberExpression)unary.Operand).Member.Name : String.Empty);
        }
    }


    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetPropertyName_Tests()
        {
            var area = new Area();

            var x = area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Id);
            var y = area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Name);
            var v = area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Created);
            var w = area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Closed);
            var z = area.GetPropertyName(a => a.Description);

            Assert.AreEqual(x, "Id");
            Assert.AreEqual(y, "Name");
            Assert.AreEqual(v, "Created");
            Assert.AreEqual(w, "Closed");
            Assert.AreEqual(z, "Description");

        }
    }
}
```